# R Package function output

Tags: r, package

I am very new to R package built.

I have a function (myFun) in package that has output like below

```
list("This is test 1","this is test 2","This is test 3",100,200,300,400,matrix(1:20,ncol=10,nrow=2))
```

I am using S3 for package.

when use the function like

```
res<-myFun(x)
```

i got the result as

```
res
list("This is test 1","this is test 2","This is test 3",100,200,300,400,matrix(1:20,ncol=10,nrow=2))
```

Now i want to use different method to show this result

1. When i will use main function myFun , expected out put is

> res<-myFun(x)
>
> res
> list("This is test 1","this is test 2","This is test3")

2. When i will use print as generic , expected output

> print(res)
>
> val<- list("This is test 1","this is test 2","This is test
> 3",100,200,300,400,matrix(1:20,ncol=10,nrow=2))

3. When i will use summary as generic , expected out put

> summary(res)
> matrix(1:20,ncol=10,nrow=2)

i can assign methods for different generic . But could not solve my expectation.

I am a bit confused how to do it in S3 or this is possible ?
Or i have to try S4, though i feel S4 is a bit complex for me to grab quickly.

I will appreciate any help or think regarding the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Just putting `res` on the console is *the same* as `print(res)`, so they cannot have different output.

Comment: Yes i have also observed so . But i want to make a difference in result `res` and `print(res)`. Thats why i am a bit confused or how to do that . Either in S3 or S4. If possible how ?

Comment: Like I said, it’s not possible (normally), nor advisable. R users **expect** these two to give the same result. Providing different results that break the user’s expectation is a very bad idea. You *could* provide an inconsistent S3 `print` method and S4 `show` method for the object but … no. Don’t.